# Find the limit of the distribution

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like some guidance with the following problem

$f_n(x)=x^4p_2(x+n)$ and we have to find  $\lim_{n\to \infty}  T_{f_{n}}$

I transformed this (correct me if I'm wrong) into $f_n(x)=x^4 \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}$ I have some similar problems in the solved exercises sessions in my uni but all of them were of the type $f_n(x)=n^a \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}$and in this case its easy since you dont have to worry about the n since when you do the integral the n goes outside but in this case its X. How do i solve this type of exercise?

Comment: What is $p_2$? What is $T_{f_n}$?

Comment: @angryavian $P_2$ is the window function  and $T_fn$ is the distributional limit

Comment: You mean $T_{f_n}(\varphi) = \int f_n(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx$?

Comment: Could you be more specific about $p_2$? What is "the window function"? Is it $\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$?

Comment: @ Yes! Sorry for the late reply